# Laravel withCount include null relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I would like withCount to include the count of non-existent relationships.

For example, let's say I have a table called `people`, and a table called `pets`.

`people` hasmany `pets`, but `pets` can have a null `people_id`. I want to get a count of the the `pets` per `people`, but I also want to include `pets` that does not have a `people_id`.

I know I can simply do `People::withCount('pets')->get()`, but this does not include a count of `pets` with null `people_id`.

The result I'm looking for would be something like:

```
person_name | pets_count
John        | 2
Mike        | 3
Joan        | 0
NULL        | 20
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: use left join with pets table https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Comment: are you want to show the result in blade or controller

Comment: i have a solution for you but needs to create a array

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use `ROLLUP`. Give it a try. It may help you.

```
People::withCount('pets')->groupBy(\DB::raw('id WITH ROLLUP'))->get();
```

to know more, please check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```
People::selectRaw('peoples.*, COUNT(pets.id) AS pets_count')
->rightJoin('pets', 'people.id', '=', 'pets.people_id')
->get()
```